# NIntegrate error message: "The integrand...has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries..."

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following problem in Mathematica. However, the problem is that R0 is an equation itself, an integral, to be more specific. So I always get the above error message.

An alternative how to solve this would be to assume an exogenous value for R0, say R0=1, and then write a loop that calculates R0 after each iteration and computes until convergence is reached. But I think there must be a more elegant solution to this.

```
\[Alpha]h = 0.2; \[Alpha]z = 0.2; \[Gamma] = 0.5; ph = 0.01; pf = \
0.1; FC = 0.1; tC = 0; TC = 0; w = 1;
\[Rho] = 0.2; \[Sigma] = 1/(1 - \[Rho]); L = 1; RA = 0.25;
G = 1; S = 1;
R0 = NIntegrate[RC[s] - RA, {s, 0, S}];
eq1 = P'[s] == -((\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (RC[s] +
          ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) )/((RC[s] + ph)^-\[Sigma]   (w + 
        G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s - FC - TC));
V = \[Alpha]h ((RC[s] + 
        ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma]))  + (\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\
\[Sigma])))^((
    1 - \[Rho])/\[Rho]) (w + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s - FC - 
      TC) - \[Gamma]  P[s] ; 
eq2 = D[V, s] == 0;
rc = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, P[S] == 0, RC[S] == RA}, RC, {s, 0, S}];
Plot[rc[s], {s, 0, S}, AxesLabel -> {s, "bid rent curve"}]
```

Maybe the problem is that I specify R0 with NIntegrate but it does not numerically integrate at that point? But I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Clear[R0]
rc = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, P[S] == 0, RC[S] == RA},RC, {s, 0, S}, R0]
```

The solution rc depends on R0!

Now you have to calculate R0 to fit your constraint

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[rc[R0][s] - RA, {s, 0, S}] == R0 , {R0, 1}]
(*{R0 -> 0.0157896}*)
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much! That works and makes a lot of sense. I wasn't aware of ParemetricNDSolveValue. Really grateful for your advice!

I still get an error message though that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries. But the result is correct - I checked it with the loop that I proposed.